# User System Methods

Tags: php, authentication, system

I don't know if this question has been asked before, but I'll go through with it.

If you were to make a system in PHP that allows users to register and login - including user levels. How entirely would you create this system. Remind yourself about sessions, what exactly is the best method you would do when being careful with sessions - this I mean by session hijacking when including passwords (hashed of course), user level, and so on. I find myself when coding a user login system, it's a bad method when using sessions to show modules, like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['user_level']))
{
    if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 3)
    {
        // show admin tools
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['user_level'] == 2)
    {
        // show moderator tools
    }
}
```

I even used something like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, username, user_level
            FROM members
            WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $uid = $row['user_id'];
            $u_name = $row['username'];
            $u_level = $row['user_level'];
        }
    }
}
```

So when I use something like this:

```
if($u_level == 3)
{
    // show admin tools
}
```

Would be a better example wouldn't it be?

Comment: You can serialize the user object and hash it along with providing the user id.  You can then retrieve this from the database with the user id and perform the same serialize, hash combination on that to check for a match.  Also, for your user levels, consider using larger numeric gaps.  This allows for inserting different user types between those you already have, such as a 'super moderator' between the admin and moderator types.

Comment: serialize and hash the user object? sounds like a bad idea... why the overhead of serializing stuff? you'll need to hit the db anyway to verify the hash... can you explain why serializing is a good idea?

Comment: You may consider revising the title of your question, as it deals less with registration and login than it does user permissions/access/session control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically bad. Here's what I do:

I set a **random** session id (`sessionid`) in the `$_COOKIE[]` array. I use cookie because I use ajax with php, which (i feel) makes things a little easier for me. Feel free to use `$_SESSION`.

Then there's a table in my database that tells me:

1. Does this session exist?
2. when did this session start?
3. when did this session last talk to the server?
4. which user does this session belong to?
5. which IP address is this session bound to?

The users table tells me the `user level` of the user.

Remember: Anything that you get from $_COOKIE is never 100% trustworthy. So never put sensitive information into them. Examples of what not to put in these variables:

1. userid -- the internal id that you use for the user (unless it is meant for the public, like the SO userid)
2. user previleges/permissions
3. other session information like last activity time or the login time

Hope this helps,
jrh

Comment: A good tip is to never store variable user data in session, just simply use the `UID`, if a user changes some profile data and your reading from the session, the user will not see until they re-login, same with permissions, incase permissions are granted during the users session, just make sure you pull them from DB on every load.. or even just update the session after every DB update.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

I personally would not try implementing a login system(a lot can go wrong with security). A lot of smart minds have put there knowledge together to specify a secure login(open-source) system. **If you still would like to know how to implement such a system safely I would advise you to look at the [OpenID](http://openid.net/), [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) specification and implemention in your language.**

1. Authentication (login): [OpenID](http://openid.net/)
2. Authorization (authorize permissions): [OAuth](http://oauth.net/)

Quote from [YAHOO](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-openid-intro.html)

> While Yahoo! uses OpenID as a
>   mechanism for authenticating users,
>   Yahoo! also uses OAuth for authorizing
>   permission to potentially sensitive
>   user data.

### Authentication

Quote from [OpenID](http://openid.net/)

> Can't remember your passwords? Tired
>   of filling out registration forms?
>   OpenID is a safe, faster, and easier
>   way to log in to web sites.

I would personally use an [OpenID-consumer library](http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries/) instead of creating one from scratch(I tried to do this and there are a lot of ins/out).

Just like Stackoverflow you would then be able to login using an OpenID. That way you don't have to store the passwords in your database yourself which is a lot saver in my opinion.

Source of information:

- [OpenID Bootcamp tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/daveman692/openid-bootcamp-tutorial)
- [A Recipe for OpenID-Enabling Your Site](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe)
- [OpenID Libraries](http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries/)

### Authorization

You could use [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) for authorization(permissions)

Quote from [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) site

> An open protocol to allow secure API
>   authorization in a simple and standard
>   method from desktop and web
>   applications.

Comment: While this is a method of creating a user login, it is not an answer to the OP's question. The OP's question deals more with session management and user permission management than registration and login.

Comment: His title says "Methods of creating a user login system". Then he should revise his title. Because openid is a user login system. But you are a little bit right I guess. Still I think this is something for security experts. A lot of users give you insecure advice. These OpenID libraries are way safer in my opinion.

Comment: OpenID is very good. But you still have to deal with user permissions.

Comment: @Ryan plus use Oauth for the authorization. I think you can't write it better yourself without a lot of effort.